# setfacl doesn't apply permissions recursively

Tags: permissions, chmod, setfacl

On my RHEL 7.7 system, I am trying to allow user foo read and execute (no write) to everything under the /var/log/ directory, to include files, sub-directories, and files within those sub-directories.  I have tried various `setfacl` commands but nothing seems to work recursively.  It allows foo to access /var/log/ with rX permissions, but nothing in any sub-directory or file below that.

I tried the following variations with no success in foo accessing sub-directories below /var/log/

```
setfacl -Rm d:u:foo:rX,u:foo:rX /var/log
setfacl -Rm u:foo:rX,d:u:foo:rX /var/log
setfacl -R -m u:foo:rX /var/log
setfacl -m u:foo:rX /var/log
```

Pretty lost at this point and I'd rather use `setfacl` over `chmod` in order to ensure future folders and files (as well as existing) allow foo the right access.

**UPDATE**: The system has selinux in enforcing mode.  I set to permissive, verified via `getenforce`, then ran my `setfacl` commands, tested with user foo and no success.  Set the system back to enforcing mode.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, not an answer but I don't have enough points to comment. It could be due to SELinux. Check status, `getenforce` or `sestatus`. If the status is enforcing, you could try `setenforce Permissive` and then repeat the commands to see if it makes any difference. Yet I do not suggest disabling SELinux. If changing status makes a difference, you should then change /var/log SE labeling.

Comment: It is in enforcing mode.  Added an update to track the troubleshooting, but setting to permissive then re-running the setfacl commands didn't seem to make it work so I set it back to enforcing.  The only thing that has worked thus far is to manually run my setfacl commands on all the directories I want user foo to access (recursive not working as expected through directories).

setfacl... /var/log | 

setfacl... /var/log/folder1 | 

setfacl.../var/log/folder2